# How to access customer info on PDP page | SCA Kilamanjaro

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

Is there a way we can access customer info like, email and name on a product detail page and access as a variable (like a handlebar variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Profile.Model** and then get the instance of the profile model like **ProfileModel.getInstance()**. There you can get the Customers data.

The other way of doing that via backend is using the Commerce API **customer**. It is inside the **Models.Init** module.

These are the methods that is available under Customer API

- addAddress(address)
- addCreditCard(creditcard)
- emailCustomer(subject, body)
- getAddress(addressid, fields)
- getAddressBook(fields)
- getCampaignSubscriptions(fields)
- getCampaignSubscriptions(subscriptionId,fields)
- getCreditCard(creditcardid, fields)
- getCreditCards(fields)
- getCustomFields()
- getCustomFieldValues()
- getFieldValues(fields)
- isGuest()
- removeAddress(addressid)
- removeCreditCard(creditcardid)
- setLoginCredentials(customer)
- updateAddress(address)
- updateCampaignSubscriptions(subscriptions)
- updateCreditCard(creditcard)
- updateProfile(customer)